# How to get a ListBox to automatically refresh entries using the item's ToString method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a `ListBox` and an `ObservableCollection<HostEntry>`. `HostEntry` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. At present, I'm binding them this way:

```
        lstHosts.DataContext = _hosts;
        lstHosts.DisplayMemberPath = "HostName";
```

Which works great. When I edit one of the HostEntries' name, the ListBox gets refreshed automatically, showing the new name.

However, I'd rather have it display the `HostEntry.ToString()` as it does by default (not setting `DiplayMemberPath`, but if I do this, the list doesn't get refreshed. I believe this is because the `HostName` property fires a `PropertyChanged` event, but there's nothing to signal that `ToString()` has changed.

Is there perhaps something I can add to this method:

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

To inform the `ListBox` that it should refresh this item?

I don't like the idea of calling `ListBox.Items.Refresh()` explicitly... what if I miss a case, or whatever there are multiple views of this list? It also shouldn't be baked into the collection, because what if I want to use different collections of `HostEntry`? Should be a way to do it somewhere inside the `HostEntry` class, no?

---

**Edit:** I want to use `ToString()` because I don't simply want to display the `HostName` property. I want to do some string formatting with some other properties, which I can easily do in `ToString()`.

Comment: can I ask why you dont want to use a property? what is the benefit of not setting the DisplayMemberPath property?

Comment: @Mark2: Because I don't want to display a simple property, I want to display a combination of properties. I need it to call a function so that I can combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databinding only works the way you want it to work with the `ToString()` method for immutable classes and structures.  That is to say, to change the value of `ToString()` you would have to replace the entry in the observable collection which the list box is prepared to handle.

If you would like to simulate full support for `ToString()` with a mutable class I am afraid you will have to create a property, call for example `AsString`, and properly notify all changes for it when anything that could affect the value.  This sort of defeats the point for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the ItemTemplate for the listbox instead of setting DisplatMemberPath like this -

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HostName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I guess this is what you want if am not wrong..??

Comment: Not quite. I wanted to use something a bit more complicated than binding it to a property. I want to use `ToString()` so that I combine some of the other properties into one display value.

Comment: For that case you can have a single property in your viewmodel to which you bind and just write your logic of combining different properties in its getter and make sure when u edit hostname u fire property change event for this property also..